# Scraping webpage with PHP

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, domdocument, fetch

I have a webpage http://dps.kse.com.pk/ticker/inc_ticker_xml.php and i want to extract all span and anchor tags values from ticker in a table. Like this LPCL, 11.06 etc
I tried curl and php dom document. It is not working. But i tried that script on other pages like google.com and yahoo.com it works on it but not on this page.

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument;


@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

//var_dump($links);

foreach ($links as $link){

     echo '<a href = "'.$link->getAttribute('href').'">' ;

     echo $link->getAttribute('href'), '<br>';
```

This code works on other pages not on http://dps.kse.com.pk/ticker/inc_ticker_xml.php page. Is there a way to scrap this page

Comment: It's because that page generates the <span> using javascript. You would most likely have to scrape the javascript codes...

Answer (score 0):

From my own php scraping experience, I discovered some servers will deny the request if the user agent isn't set. Once I set the user agent in the curl settings, my script scraped fine :)

This should help :-
http://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof

Comment: ah ok. can you try echoing out the $html after the file_get_contents call to see if it's getting anything back from the remote server?

Comment: tell me the problem, there is no error in my code just tell me the way to scrap this page

Answer (score 0):

This site requires cookie and javascript are to be enabled. So if you request the site, you'll get something like below on the html source.

```
setCookie('YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666', '219.109.39.29', 10);
location.href = getHostUri();
```

You have to parse the Cookie value from there and need to send through CURL like below.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: YPF8827340282Jdskjhfiw_928937459182JAX666=219.109.39.29"));
```

After that you'll find a different source that will have lot more javascript/ajax calls. Trace the calls(with any network protocol analyzer like wireshark) if you need to parse content of ajax.

But, best of luck for this tedious task :-)