# How do I fetch specific values from a Wordpress Product to insert them into a HTML file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Please I need your help, I created this code and it's supposed to show a WordPress product:

```
<a class="product" href="#">
      <figure class="product__figure">
        <img
          class="product__figure__img"
          src="#"
          alt="Product Image"
        />
        <figcaption class="product__figure__figcaption">
          <h3 class="product__title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h3>
          <span class="product__price">0.00 <span class="euro">€</span></span>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
      <span class="product__button">Options</span>
    </a>
```

I have 2 div which contain each 4 times this code, the purpose is to fetch the name/price/img and permalink of the 8 most recent products in my WooCommerce and insert theses values into my code so that when a new product is added, the code update automatically... The only problem? I suspect that I will have to use Javascript or PHP but I know absolutely nothing about these 2...

I don't know how to do...

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a processing language, it is only a content language. If a website is a house, HTML is the walls, doors, windows, floors. CSS is the wallpaper, the paint, the decor, etc. Javascript (amongst others) is the electricity that runs through the house, making the fridge actually cold, turning on the lights, adding heat or air conditioning. In this metaphor, HTML's walls and floors are the text, images, and links on a website. CSS's decor is the coloring, font, placement of those texts and images. Javascript is what makes stuff happen to those texts and images, whether it's adding a function to a button to make it dance when it's clicked, or sending a message to an inbox when a contact form is filled out.

It would take me a long, long time to write the code you need (not necessarily because of the complexity, I'm just slow at this lol), but what I can tell you is that there are hundreds of Wordpress plugins that will do exactly what you want it to do, and in fact i'm 90% sure that whichever WP plugin you're using for your woocommerce site already has a function for that. If you can provide information about what plugin you're using then I can direct you on how to find that function!

Comment: I think I was not very clear in my question I'm sorry, I'm creating a 100% HTML homepage with VSCode but I need to retrieve product information from a WordPress. So, I can't put a plugin in my HTML code... Can I? Basically, I think I need a JS code that will fetch the external informations I need (name/price/img/link of the eight most recent products) and inject them into specific places in my HTML. My code roughly looks like this: ```<div> <a> <a> <a> <a> </div> <div> <a> <a> <a> <a> </div>```

Comment: @Paul gotcha. That is a *significantly* more complex question. You will need to create what's called a "scraper," which will scrape a specified URL for information based on certain tags. Additionally, WordPress offers security measures to block scraping as most shops don't want people stealing their listings. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/10/web-scraping-using-node-js/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66717912/web-scraping-in-javascript
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299656/scraping-webpage-with-php

Comment: @paul more info: https://pressidium.com/blog/protect-your-wordpress-website-from-content-scraping/
I've been doing web development for 10 years, and I'm starting to learn more processing languages like Javascript. I'm still very new to it, but even with that consideration I would not be able to build a javascript scraper in fewer than 100 hours. BUT if you have access to the WP site, you may be able to use an API to connect content from one site to another. I'm unsure about how to do this from WP to an outside site though.... 2/3

Comment: @paul Last one I promise... You may have more success asking a question on SO phrased like, "Can I use an API plugin to pull shop listings from a WordPress site to an externally hosted website?" if you have access to the WP. If not, you'll want to ask, "What do I need to learn in order to build a webpage scraper?" You may have more luck getting answers from Reddit on the 2nd question, as SO tends to dislike vague questions like that.

Comment: Ok Got it, I Indeed have access to WP and the product list, I am simply recreating the home page in HTML to improve the performance and SEO of my website. I'll look forward with the links you sent me. Thanks again !

Comment: @Paul check this out! https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-export/ If you can add a plugin to your WP, this (or a similar plugin) may be able to help you. I literally just had to start learning javascript a few months ago for a new job, and I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkZNo7MFNFg and did the tutorial on freecodecamp.org at the same time. I haven't worked XML with JS, but I bet you can figure it out :)